# How to pass Id from One View to Another MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**Problem:** 
I have List of Categories with SubCategories, so when i click on SubCategory item it redirect me to List of Entries. There along the list it has Create ActionLink. So the problem is passing the SubCategoryId when I click SubCategoryItem for the Create ActionLink. Without the CreateActionLink it lists the entries but with it, it gives an error in the index view:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 6:  
Line 7:  <p>
Line 8:      @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { subCategoryId = @Model.SubCategoryId})
Line 9:  </p>
Line 10:
```

I understand that i am passing null reference and the question is how to avoid that? 
Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public class EntryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {        
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult EntryList(int subCategoryId)
    {
        var entries = EntryDAL.GetEntries(subCategoryId);
        return View("_EntryList",entries);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(int subCategoryId)
    {
        var model = new Entry();

        model.SubCategoryId = subCategoryId;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Entry entry)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var add = EntryDAL.Add(entry);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(entry);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

}
```

IndexView:

```
@model PasswordCloud.Domain.Models.SubCategory

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { subCategoryId = @Model.SubCategoryId })
</p>

@{Html.RenderPartial("_EntryList",Model.EntryList);}
```

PartialView:

```
@model IEnumerable<PasswordCloud.Domain.Models.Entry>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubCategoryId)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategoryId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

SubCategoryListItem View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PasswordCloud.Domain.Models.SubCategory>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

@Html.ActionLink(item.Name,"Index","Entry", new { subCategoryId = item.SubCategoryId }, null)
}
```

Comment: I just read your question twice and have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do.  Please restate.

Comment: In Create() why are you catching an `Exception` but not handling it? Where does the null ref exception get thrown? Specifically, what is null?

Comment: It looks like EntryList should push up the SUbcategoryID, but it isn't because it's not part of the model.  You have to create a model class with the list of entries, or push the SubdcategoryID in ViewData/ViewBag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Index action you never create a model and pass it to the view.  So when it gets to your line where you make the action link where you use `new { subCategoryId = @Model.SubCategoryId}` your model is null.  Thus you get a null ref exception.  To fix it you need to do something like this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    var model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it;s working upon your suggestion, but now when i include @{Html.RenderPartial("_EntryList",Model.EntryList);} it throws an error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PasswordCloud.Domain.Models.SubCategory', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PasswordCloud.Domain.Models.Entry]'. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It is telling you that Model.EntryList is a SubCategory but your _EntryList view wants an IEnumerable<Entry>.  You have a type mismatch.  If you keep having problems, ask a new question.  That way more people will see it and will be able to help you.